# Setting datestyle = 'SQL, DMY' fails

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc

I'm running the following command:
SET datestyle = 'SQL, DMY';
And then using the datestyle type to create a table. Turns out I get the following message:

```
  [Code: , SQL State: 08006]  The server's DateStyle parameter was changed to 
  SQL, DMY. The JDBC driver requires DateStyle to begin with ISO for correct 
  operation.
```

So I've tried
SET datestyle = 'ISO, DMY';
This works but it's not working with my table.
When I set the type of the column to text I get this:

[image]

I want the exact same thing but with datestyle. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand to JDBC, but this can be done on SQL level via `to_timestamp` function:

```
postgres=# select to_timestamp('13/01/2016 16:28', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi');
┌────────────────────────┐
│      to_timestamp      │
╞════════════════════════╡
│ 2016-01-13 16:28:00+01 │
└────────────────────────┘
 (1 row)
```

So you can pass yours dates to Postgres as string, and the conversation can be done inside Postgres.